# Is there a strictly-decreasing sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\rightarrow1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does there exists a strictly decreasing sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that 
$x_n \rightarrow 0$ and $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\rightarrow1$ ?

Comment: $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @DR.X Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Let consider

$$x_n=\frac 1 n$$

or more in general for $a>0$

$$x_n=\frac 1 {n^a}$$

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: @DR.X You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

$X_n$=$1/n$ should come to your mind first then raise any positive power to $n$, the result still holds.

Comment: thanks for your anwer